# Why is background-image not working in css but works in html?

Tags: html, css

So I have two sections in my HTML5, and I titled one section id = "section_2". In my CSS3, I tried to do:

```
#section_2{
   background-image: url(image.jpg);
}
```

However, this did not work.
So when I went into my HTML5 and put  right under the  tag, it worked.

This is strange because when I do things like,

```
#aside{
   background-image: url(image.jpg);
}
```

it works.

Comment: Actually, I have a new issue. Adding the img in HTML pushed back other elements that share space with section_2, and I assume this is because it's not a background image.

Comment: Also, if it helps, the elements in section 2 are floated to the left.

Comment: Relative URLs in CSS are relative to CSS file itself. Can you tell us your directory tree? If your CSS file is inside a folder, you will have to use `../` to go "one directory up" `../image.jpg` also check your Network console for errors (Chrome devtools)

Comment: Solved it, I just contained everything in a <div> then used background image from there and make overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could have an issue with the relative location of the image.jpg. When called from with the page the url must be relative to the page. When called from within the CSS file, it must be relative to the CSS file, not necessarily the page.

e.g.

```
index.html
css/style.css
image.jpg
```

You may need for example:

```
background-image: url('../image.jpg');
```

You could also be experience an issue with the level of importance, depending on how many background-image attributes are being applied, in which case try using !important.

```
background-image: url(image.jpg) !important;
```

Be certain that the image.jpg is relative to the style.css location.